# Combine RSS Items Into a Single Item

Tags: rss, concatenation, yahoo-pipes

I'm working on building an app which will take multiple RSS feeds and combine them into a single feed.  So far so good, I'm able to do this via Yahoo Pipes easily enough.

What I'm having problems figuring out how to do, is to take the items from the output of that Pipe and combine them into a single item.

Basically what the goal here is, is that on my site I tag various posts which drops them into an RSS feed on the site.  Then I want to be able to automatically publish a top 10 blog post (using ifttt.com) based on the items which I've tagged over the course of the week.  To make all this work I need to get the top 10 items from my normal tag (which I'm using Yahoo Pipes to handle) into a single item so that ifttt.com can feed that over to my WordPress site as a blog post.

Any ideas are welcome, with one exception.  I'm on a hosted WordPress site, so I can't install plugins for WordPress.  If that's the only option, I can probably make it work by putting the plugin on one of the other WordPress sites that I own.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a wordpress plugin on another site.  The plugin is called WP-RSSImport.